# Update Onedrive in File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I want to use File Explorer for faster access to Onedrive, but for some reason, the Onedrive in File Explorer does not sync at all, it remains the same all the time with no update. How can I get it properly sync?

[image]

P.S. The Onedrive app and webpage version all work perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you sign in to OneDrive and go through the initial setup, declaring what folders you want synced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these ways in the following article.

**2.** Check if your OneDrive account is connected to Windows 10

**4.** Complete the OneDrive setup process

**6.** Check your PC's available storage space

**7.** Check for conflicting files or folders in the same location

**9.** When nothing else is working, reset OneDrive

Reference:

**9 tips to help you fix OneDrive sync problems on Windows 10**

https://www.windowscentral.com/9-tips-help-you-fix-onedrive-sync-problems-windows-10

Comment: You're right, I think somehow the oneDrive is not properly set up, after reinstalled and went through the setup, it syncs now. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. I am so glad the problem has been resolved.